# scala - How to get a map with the Typesafe config library

Tags: scala, configuration, configuration-files

i have my configuration file looks like this  so which the best way to do this ?

```
configs=[
{c1="bla bla",
c2="bla bla",
c3="bla bla"},
{c1="bla bla",
c2="bla bla",
c3="bla bla"},
{c1="bla bla",
c2="bla bla",
c3="bla bla"}
]
```

Comment: do you think TypeSafe config  do the triks ?

Comment: Try Typesafe config + PureConfig

Comment: thank you TypeSafe config can resolve the problem with getObjectList("configs") and getStringList ...

Comment: You can try my scala wrapper: https://github.com/andr83/scalaconfig

Comment: thanks i solved the problem but it's nice solution as well